# Selectize: Setting Default Value in onInitialize with setValue

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I have a web application with multiple Selectize objects initialized on the page. I'm trying to have each instance load a default value based on the query string when the page loads, where `?<obj.name>=<KeywordID>`. All URL parameters have already been serialized are are a dictionary call `that.urlParams`.

I know there are other ways to [initializing Selectize with a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962124/how-to-set-a-value-for-a-selectize-js-input) I could try; but, I'm curious why calling `setValue` inside `onInitialize` isn't working for me because I'm getting any error messages when I run this code.

I'm bundling all this JavaScript with Browserify, but I don't think that's contributing to this problem.

In terms of debugging, I've tried logging `this` to the console inside `onInititalize` and found that `setValue` is up one level in the Function.prototype property, the `options` property is full of data from `load`, the key for those objects inside `options` corresponds to the KeywordID. But when I log `getValue(val)` to the console, I get an empty string. Is there a way to make this work or am I ignoring something about Selectize or JavaScript?

```
module.exports = function() {    
    var that = this;

    ...

    this.selectize = $(this).container.selectize({
        valueField: 'KeywordID',  // an integer value
        create: false,
        labelField: 'Name',
        searchField: 'Name',
        preload: true,
        allowEmptyOptions: true,
        closeAfterSelect: true,
        maxItems: 1,
        render: {
           option: function(item) {
                return that.template(item);
            },
        },
        onInitialize: function() {
            var val = parseInt(that.urlParams[that.name], 10);  // e.g. 5
            this.setValue(val);
        },
        load: function(query, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: that.url,
                type: 'GET',
                error: callback,
                success: callback
            })
        }
    });

};

...
```

Comment: have you tried using the `options` property?
 https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md

Comment: When the page loads, I only know the `valueField` via url parameter, so I need load to fetch the data from the API before I can map the `valueField` to its option object, then select it that option default value via `setValue`. I think the problem with the above code is that `onInitialize` fires before `load` does, even if `preload: true`. 

I might try having the data already bootstrapped into the page when it loads, and see if `onInitialize` behaves the way I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After sprinkling in some `console.logs` into Selectize.js, I found that the ajax data hadn't been imported, when the initialize event was triggered. I ended up finding a solution using `jQuery.when()` to make `setValue` fire after the data had been loaded, but I still wish I could find a one-function-does-one-thing solution.

```
module.exports = function() {    
    var that = this;

    ...

    this.selectize = $(this).container.selectize({
        valueField: 'KeywordID',  // an integer value
        create: false,
        labelField: 'Name',
        searchField: 'Name',
        preload: true,
        allowEmptyOptions: true,
        closeAfterSelect: true,
        maxItems: 1,
        render: {
           option: function(item) {
                return that.template(item);
            },
        },
        load: function(query, callback) {
            var self = this;
            $.when( $.ajax({
                url: that.url,
                type: 'GET',
                error: callback,
                success: callback
            }) ).then(function() {
                var val = parseInt(that.urlParams[that.name], 10);  // e.g. 5
                self.setValue(val);
            });
        }
    });

};

...
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the option before setting it as the value, as this line in `addItem` will be checking for it:
`if (!self.options.hasOwnProperty(value)) return;`

inside onInitialize you would do:

```
var val = that.urlParams[that.name]; //It might work with parseInt, I haven't used integers in selectize options though, only strings.
var opt = {id:val, text:val};
self.addOption(opt);
self.setValue(opt.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `onInitialize` you could add a `load` trigger to the selectize. This will fire after the load has finished and will execute `setValue()` as expected.

```
var $select = $(this).container.selectize({
    // ...
    load: function(query, callback) {
        // ...
    }
});
var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
selectize.on('load', function(options) {
    // ...
    selectize.setValue(val);
});
```

Note that for this you first have to get the selectize instanze (`$select[0].selectize`).

Answer (score 0):

in my case it need refresh i just added another command beside it

```
                $select[0].selectize.setValue(opt);
```

i added this
$select[0].selectize.options[opt].selected = true;

and changes applied

but i dont know why?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize each `selectize`' selected value by setting the `items` property. Fetch the value from your querystring then add it as an item of the `items` property value:

```
const selectedValue = getQueryStringValue('name') //set your query string value here

$('#sel').selectize({
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'title',
    preload: true,
    options: [
        { id: 0, title: 'Item 1' },
        { id: 1, title: 'Item 2' },
    ],
    items: [ selectedValue ],
});
```

Since it accepts array, you can set multiple selected items