# Adding new options to an initialised selectize element

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I'm trying to replicate the solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962124/how-to-set-a-value-for-a-selectize-js-input/32958104#32958104) but having no luck.  I need to add a new *selected* option to an already-initialised `selectize` element that may or may not already list it as an `<item>` option.  My code:

```
<select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="countries"></select>
<button type="button" onclick="addFiji();">Add "Fiji"</button>

<script>
function addFiji(){
  var selectElement = $('#countries').eq(0);
  var selectize = selectElement.data('selectize');
  if (!!selectize) selectize.setValue("Fiji");
  alert('Nothing happens. How can we add Fiji?');
}

var countries = [{"name":""}, {"name":"Afghanistan"}, {"name":"Belgium"}, {"name":"China"},{"name":"Denmark"}, {"name":"Estonia"}, {"name":"Finland"}, {"name":"Greece"}];

$.ajax({
  url: '/echo/json/',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { json: JSON.stringify(countries) },
  error: function(err) { console.log(err); },
  success: function(options) {
    $('#countries').selectize({
    valueField: 'name',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: 'name',
    maxItems: 3,
    preload: true,
    options: options,
    create: false,
    });
    } 
});
</script>
```

See [jsfiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/a1v9oarh/) (and [jsfiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/a1v9oarh/1/) for an alternative method). Neither of these has any effect.  Grateful for any pointers where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Did you try `add` event => `selectize.addOption(options);
selectize.refreshOptions(true);` or `addItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gvc5bev/)):

```
function addFiji()
{
    var $select = $('#countries').selectize();
    var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
    selectize.addOption({"name":"Fiji"});
    selectize.addItem('Fiji');
    selectize.refreshOptions();
}
```