# selectize, select an option

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I'm using `selectize` [this](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) tool that let's me make a select field searchable.
The thing though is I can't select an option, useful when editing existing data.

The code looks like this to instantiate selectize

```
$('#vendor').selectize({
    sortField: 'text'
});
```

I can select something then find it's value on the console using `$('#vendor').val();` but after refreshing and doing `$('#vendor').val('21');` which is the value I got back, it doesn't select the option.

This normally works on a normal select field.

Comment: So found a question that answers this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962124/how-to-set-a-value-for-a-selectize-js-input